# rank in MPI_Bcast

Tags: mpi

```
MPI_Bcast(void *buffer,  int count,  MPI_Datatype datatype,  int root,  MPI_Comm comm)
```

This function does not require the rank parameter. How does it know the rank of each process?

We should call the `MPI_COMM_RANK()` before broadcast, does any data structure (like communicator) store the rank of processes?

Comment: i would also read the documentation, http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Bcast.3.php, open-mpi has one of the best doc's for MPI

Comment: @pyCthon, the Open MPI documentation is just `man`-friendly version of the text found in the [MPI-2.2 standards document](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf) (which is fine - no need to reinvent the wheel and to duplicate the efforts behind the excellent wording in the standard).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you didn't think it possible, but functions inside the MPI library can make internally the same MPI calls that you do use to obtain the process' rank or the size of a communicator. That's why `MPI_Bcast()` doesn't need the rank of the calling process because it simply calls the internal implementation of `MPI_Comm_rank()` in order to obtain it. Here is a small sample from one of the `MPI_Bcast()` implementations in Open MPI (more specifically, this is from the split binary tree implementation in the `tuned` module from the `coll` framework that provides algorithms implementing the collective operations):

```c
int
ompi_coll_tuned_bcast_intra_split_bintree ( void* buffer,
                                            int count, 
                                            struct ompi_datatype_t* datatype, 
                                            int root,
                                            struct ompi_communicator_t* comm,
                                            mca_coll_base_module_t *module,
                                            uint32_t segsize )
{
    ...
    int rank, size;
    ...

    size = ompi_comm_size(comm);
    rank = ompi_comm_rank(comm);

    ...
}
```

As you can see, it calls the internal implementation of `MPI_Comm_size()` and `MPI_Comm_rank()`. These are very cheap calls in Open MPI. The rank of the process is stored in the *process group* that is associated with the communicator and is copied to a field in the communicator structure (to save a few CPU cycles dereferencing the pointer to the group) during the creation of a communicator (for more information refer to `openmpi-source/ompi/communicator/communicator.h` and `openmpi-source/ompi/group/group.h`).

As a matter of fact, no MPI communication primitive ever takes explicitly the rank of the calling process - it is always resolved internally. You only specify where to send the data (e.g. in `MPI_SEND`) or from where to receive the data (e.g. in `MPI_RECV`) or the data root in those collective operations which have one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider three possible implementations of `MPI_Bcast()`:

1. The *root* sends to `root+1`, and then sends to `root+2`, and then to `root+3`, etc. This is a linear order of magnitude
2. Starting with the *root*, each process that has a copy of the data at iteration `N` forwards the data to `rank xor 2^N`. This is logarithmic order of magnitude.
3. The *root* uses the router to perform a multicast to each process on the network. This is constant order of magnitude.

In each of these scenarios, the `MPI_Bcast()` function knows which process will get the next message. In the first and third case, any *non-root* process will simply receive the data; in the second, each process will continue the forwarding process once it receives the data. In all implementations, though, the order of sends and receives is deterministic on the bases of which process is the *root*. (That's why all processes must invoke `MPI_Bcast()`, whether *root* or not.)

Comment: Nice explanation but it doesn't touch on the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the rank is stored in the communicator, and is available to the implementation of `MPI_Bcast` internally.  Ranks are assigned when a communicator is created.  For example, `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is created by `MPI_Init`.

`MPI_Comm_rank` simply gets the rank value from the communicator.  There's no requirement to call it before a broadcast.  However, knowing the rank is usually necessary to do any meaningful programming.

Note that since `MPI_Bcast` is a collective call, it needs to be performed by all processes in the communicator.

Comment: Just to clarify: rank is the identifier (index) of the process in the process group associated with particular communicator.

Comment: @HristoIliev OK, I'm being pedantic :)  The other answer could be misleading though: the question explicitly asks if calling `MPI_Comm_rank` is required before `MPI_Bcast`, and the answer makes it sound like it is.

Comment: Being pedantic is good, especially where standards are involved :)

Answer (score -1):

`int root` , is the rank of the broadcast root, essentially MPI broadcast sends a message from rank root to all the other ranks

also it would be considered by me a "best practice" to call the following after MPI_Init

```
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
```

this will assign each processor or core a int rank value from 0 to n-1

and

```
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Numprocs);
```

this will create an int with Numproces being the total number of processors

Comment: Just to clarify: MPI_Comm_rank and MPI_Comm_size do *not* assign ranks or sizes.  These are simply accessors to retrieve the values of rank and size from the communicator.